# How do magical mortals affect technology?

Tags: dresden-files

I cant find this is the rule book but it may be there. but mechanically speaking how do I as a GM factor this in?

I assume this would be consistent but higher probability when considering a wizard compared to a minor talent.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spellcasters affect technology.  Treat it as a compel if you're trying to make their lives difficult, or just a skill check if they're doing it deliberately.  (A very easy skill check, as I recall the chart).

If you're talking in terms of non-spellcasters hexing stuff?  Doesn't happen.  It's pretty explicitly tied to the spellcasting powers -- ritual and channeling, thaumaturgy and evocation.

Comment: Oh, and note that it's explicitly mentioned that "technology that was around whenever the spell caster was born" seems to be a fuzzy cutoff for what is and isn't affected by any given character; A wizard in their late teens today would presumably be able to use a mobile phone or old desktop computer, though probably not a smartphone or tablet.